# How to make discord role command case insensitive for inputs

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I have this discord bot code that gives users roles:

```
@client.command(aliases=['r'], case_insensitive=True)
async def role(ctx, *, role: discord.Role):
  if role in ctx.author.roles:
    await ctx.author.remove_roles(role)
  else:
    await ctx.author.add_roles(role)
```

However, when a user inputs a role it is case sensitive. For example, if you wanted the role "Coder" and did the command !role coder, it would not give you the role as it is lowercase when the role is uppercase. I would like it to give the role anyway. I tried experimenting with the capitalize() Method but I have not figured anything out.

Answer (score 0):

I just realised my previous answer wasn't really relevant. What you would rather want to do is something like this :

1. Remove the `discord.Role` hint on line to. This would turn `role` into a string, which can be lowered.
2. Search across the guild roles any role with a matching name.
3. Check if the user already have the role. If he does, remove it, if not, give him.

I ended up with this code :

```py
@client.command(aliases=['r'], case_insensitive=True)
async def role(ctx, *, role): # Step 1 : Removing discord.Role hint to make role a string
    print(role)
    requested_role = role.lower()
    matching_role = None # This variable will hold the role to give or remove, if any
    # Step 2 : Search across the server roles any matching roles
    for role in ctx.guild.roles:
        if role.name.lower() == requested_role:
            # A role with that name is found
            matching_role = role
            break
    if matching_role == None:
        await ctx.send("No role found with that name")
    else:
        # Step 3 : Give or remove the role
        if matching_role in ctx.author.roles:
            await ctx.author.remove_roles(matching_role)
            await ctx.send("I removed the role " + matching_role.name + " from " + ctx.author.name)
        else:
            await ctx.author.add_roles(matching_role)
            await ctx.send("I gave the role " + matching_role.name + " to " + ctx.author.name)
```

I tried this approch on my own bot, it looks like it works just fine :
[image: It looks like it works on my own bot]

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thank you but when I try to use this code to give an example role called "Test' it only works when i write the correct case, which in this case is "Test" with a capital T.

Comment: @interactiveBloopers Yeah, I just realised my previous answer was not that relevant. I edited it, now it should be good. Have a nice day 